# Selenium / python, проблема с кликом на кнопу после загрузки изображения при создании объекта на сайте

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, fileupload

Всем привет. Появилась необходимость проверять подгружается ли изображение при создании объекта в веб приложении. Загружаю изображение при помощи input который спрятан в кнопке. Из скриншетов и видео с Selenium Grid сервера видно что изображение подгружается, а кнопка сохранить нажимается но не срабатывает, интересно что клик по кнопке проходит, и ошибки в тесте не возникает. Проблема возникает только при запуске тестов через CI/CD на GitLab. При запуске теста локально все отлично работает.
код следующий

```
self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="file"]').send_keys("test-1.jpg")
self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()= "save"]/..'))).click()
```

я пробовал делать клики:

1. без ожидания
2. с использованием CSS селектора, xpath, id
3. при помощи JS
4. при помощи цикла в котором происходит клик, после чего идет ожидание того что окно создания объекта закрылось, и если окно не закрылось делается еще один клик по кнопке сохранить и так 10 раз.
   Но результат один, клик происходит но действие кнопки не выполняется. Мы всей командой не можем понять в чем дело, может кто то сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Нужна ссылка на сайт, так трудно что-то сказать.